# Развертывание FastAPI на VDS

Tags: python, vds, gunicorn, fastapi

Разворачиваю на VDS приложение по [инструкции](https://pythobyte.com/deploy-fastapi-application-on-ubuntu-with-nginx-gunicorn-and-uvicorn-3mbl-f789b2df/)
Делал все по инструкции за исключением:

> listen NUMBER_PORT;

> proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:NUMBER_PORT;

> main:app ---(заменил на)-->wsgi:uvicorn

В мануале после команды:

```
sudo systemctl start myapp.service
```

Должно все работать - а у меня если проверить через:

```
sudo systemctl status myapp.service
```

Горит красная лампочка. И, соответственно, если зайти на адрес - там **502 ошибка**

Точка входа(wsgi.py):

```
import uvicorn

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("main:app", port=NUMBER_PORT_LOC, host='0.0.0.0', reload=True)
```

Если вручную запустить через:

```
python wsgi.py
```

то все работает...

**В чем проблема? Что не так?**

Comment: Вы уж определитесь, каким именно способом вы запускаете приложение — python, gunicorn, uvicorn? Когда определитесь, пропишите правильную команду запуска в `ExecStart`, не забудьте выполнить `systemctl daemon-reload` и вместо «красной лампочки» читайте текст ошибки в статусе

Comment: @andreymal, точку входа я по аналогии другого приложения взял, которое работает сейчас на другом порту (но там Flask-приложение, поэтому настройки адаптировал).  Как сделать чтобы python сам запускал **wsgi.py** ,  которую вручную ввожу  **python wsgi.py**

Comment: Надо не «по аналогии», а так, как вы сами предусмотрели его запуск. Если ваше приложение нужно запускать командой `python wsgi.py` — значит именно так в `ExecStart` и пропишите (только systemd требует полный путь к исполняемому файлу, то есть что-то вроде `/usr/bin/python` или `/путь/к/виртуальному/окружению/bin/python` в зависимости от способа установки)

Comment: Ну и конечно же не забудьте правильный `WorkingDirectory` (чтобы этот самый файл `wsgi.py` вообще нашёлся) и правильные `User` и `Group`, у которых есть доступ на чтение и запись нужных файлов приложения

Comment: @andreymal, решил попробовать запустить как в инструкции - запустилось и работает. но получается, что он сейчас работает на порту по умолчанию **8000** А если я еще захочу приложение запустить на FastApi - уже ведь не получится, т.к. порт занят будет. Как задать ему порт запуска?

Comment: Если вы зачем-то запустили приложение через gunicorn (зачем?), значит читайте [документацию gunicorn](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#bind)

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо =) Во-общем, я разобрался и запустил через **wsgi.py**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодаря @andreymal, я разобрался. Оставлю решение, если кому пригодится в будущем:

1. *sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/NAME_SERVISE.service*

```
[Unit]
 Description= instance to serve NAME_SERVISE
 After=network.target
[Service]
 User=USER
 Group=www-data
 WorkingDirectory=/home/USER/MY_APP_FOLDER
 Environment="PATH=/home/USER/MY_APP_FOLDER/myprojectenv/bin"
 ExecStart=/home/USER/MY_APP_FOLDER/myprojectenv/bin/python  wsgi.py
[Install]
 WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

2. *Файл wsgi.py:*

```
import uvicorn
if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("main:app", port=NUMBER_PORT_LOCAL, host='0.0.0.0', reload=True)
```

3. *sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/NAME_SERVISE*

```
server {
    listen NUMBER_PORT_GLOBAL;
    server_name IP_ADDRES;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:NUMBER_PORT_LOCAL;
    }
}
```

5. *Создаем символьную ссылку:*

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/NAME_SERVISE /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

4. *Ну и типичные команды (запуск/автозагрузка/проверка статуса):*

```
sudo systemctl start NAME_SERVISE
sudo systemctl enable NAME_SERVISE
sudo systemctl status NAME_SERVISE
```